# Intermittent Connection Refused Error

Tags: android, wcf, iis-7.5

I am a bit new to developing WCF services and am running into two issues when invoking a WCF web service from an Android app.

1. Intermittent Connection Refused Error (HttpHostConnectException) - This happens if I attempt to connect to the web service after a few minutes of inactivity.
2. Connection reset by peer - This occurs when one specific web service method has to process a lot of records. This same method works fine for smaller results sets. I suspect this may have to do with the ASP.NET process worker and I have been experimenting with different timeout intervals in IIS but the problem persists.

Any help with the above is greatly appreciated.

Setup:

- IIS7.5 running on a Windows Server 8 machine with a single process worker
- Enabled IIS Authentication Modes: Anonymous, Windows
- Android v 2.3.3 referencing JCIFS library for NTLM authentication
- Calling a RESTful WCF Web Service using HTTP POST
- WCF Session State *Mode="Off", CookieLess = "UseDeviceProfile", regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"*

Thanks,

J.D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one is interested to know the solution: I was able to eliminate the intermittent connection refused error by making the following two changes:

- Disabled the Anonymous Authentication and set up the HTTPClient to
  connect using NTLM Authentication
- Instead of instantiating a new HTTPClient for each new HTTPPost request, I reuse a single instance for all requests during the life of the application and closed the connection once the app itself was shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need to worry about client-side timeouts, as those are not WCF errors (or at least not ones I've seen before).  I'm not much good with Android and as usual there's not a lot out there for help, but I would start with both connection and receive timeouts to see if that improves the situation.